# How can I find where a variable is located in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repository [WWBN/AVideo](https://github.com/WWBN/AVideo) and I want to change the text that appears on a button.

I viewed the page source and the button is defined as `subscribeButton1`. Now I need to find out which file this variable is located so I can change the text associated with it. How can I do that?

Here is what I want to find:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `git`:

```
git grep -Fw subscribeButton1
```

Option [`-F`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--F) is to use fixed string; option [`-w`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--w) is to search a whole word.

Using Github:

https://github.com/WWBN/AVideo/search?q=subscribeButton1 — nothing found

https://github.com/WWBN/AVideo/search?q=subscribeButton — found 2 places, "1" is a `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But you see, how can I change it so the text on the button is different utilizing what you found? I want to replace "subscribe" with "employ" on the button.

Comment: `git grep -Fw -Ovim subscribeButton` to call `vim` editor on the found files.